# I need to delete a string in multiple lines from a file using batch script

Tags: string, batch-file

```
Working file: Projects/fentbase/common/javasrc/validators/PasswordSetupVal.java 
Working file: Projects/fentbase/channeladministration/spec/ui/dev/ppdl/AccessSchemeMaintenancePreview.dppdl 
Working file: Projects/fentbase/common/javasrc/validators/EmailValidator.java 
Working file: Projects/fentbase/common/javasrc/validators/MailIdVal.java
```

I have this in a file. I need to take out "Working file: " from every line. Please let me know how do I do that.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to skin the cat:

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%i in ('type "file.txt"') do @echo(%%j
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
    set line=%%a
    echo !line:Working file=!
)
```

Usage:

```
sciprt.cmd file.txt > new_file.txt
move /y new_file.txt file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
type "file.txt" | repl "Working file: " "" L >"newfile.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.